# How to host a dedicated server for WSO2EMM?

Tags: wso2, wso2-iot

I have no trouble making WSO2EMM work on my local machine. The problem is I want to upload it to a server, but I am having a hard time finding a server that supports WSO2Carbon.

Is there any hosting sites available I can put it or if not, is it possible I can host it myself?

Comment: Upload it to a server and go through the documentation on how to run it as a service

Comment: @ItuokeAjanlekoko Upload to a server? Could you specify where? I already tried Heroku and OpenShift. 
Also, the documentation does not contain anything about cloud deployment.

Comment: Try getting a hosted cloud base VM. Preferable Linux distro configured. Upload the file and go through the documentation. I thought I would be able to write a blog on setting it up. But, can't do that this week

Comment: WSO2 carbon it self act as a server , you just have to copy the artifact in to a server of your choice and start the wso2 sever.